# Troubleshooting Google Sheets importxml

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, xpath, google-sheets-formula

Having an issue with a site that changed recently. I had a working formula here, but I haven't been able to update it.

`=IMPORTXML("https://fundrise.com/offerings/8/view","//div[contains(@class,'statistic__value')]")`

I've also tried using a full-path approach, with no success.

`=IMPORTXML("https://fundrise.com/offerings/8/view","//html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]")`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scraping data to Google Sheets from a website that uses JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74237688/scraping-data-to-google-sheets-from-a-website-that-uses-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

This site requires javascript. You can no longer use native functions like importhtml, importxml.

[How to know if Google Sheets IMPORTDATA, IMPORTFEED, IMPORTHTML or IMPORTXML functions are able to get data](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/115664/how-to-know-if-google-sheets-importdata-importfeed-importhtml-or-importxml-fun)