# Is there a reliable method to automatically update CeX prices in real-time?

Tags: google-sheets, import, real-time

I am trying to build a spreadsheet which records the buying and selling prices from the website CeX, but where the document updates the prices as they change in real time. The data isn't organized into a specific table, which seems to make things more difficult.

I have tried various different things, but none of them seem to work at all. Mainly, I have tried importxml and importhtml, but I'm just really lost. Can anyone give me any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Troubleshooting Google Sheets importxml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72846455/troubleshooting-google-sheets-importxml)